# Python-Extract longest sequence from a multi Fasta File?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I have seen that this question already has answers elsewhere but that involves using Biopython. I dont want to include additional libraries as it would slow down my implementation. Can anyone suggest any way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

FASTA is a very simple format, so you can roll your own parser in a few lines of code, e.g.

```
def iter_fasta(path):
    with open(path) as handle:
        header = None
        buf = []
        for line in handle:
            if line.isspace():
                continue  # Omit empty lines.

            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith(">"):
                if buf:
                    assert header is not None
                    yield header, "".join(buf)
                    del buf[:]

                header = line[1:]  # Drop the '>'.
            else:
                buf.append(line)

        # Handle the last record.
        if buf:
            yield header, "".join(buf)
```

The longest sequence would then be

```
longest = max(iter_fasta(path), key=lambda p: len(p[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried running your code and it seems to run perfectly without 'assert header is not None'. If i include that line it gives me an assertionerror. Can u please explain the usefulness of that statement. Thank You.

Comment: `assert header is not None` is here to make sure we read proper FASTA. It can only fire if the file a) is not in FASTA format, e.g. a list of sequences without the names, or b) starts with something other than `">"`, e.g. a whitespace character. I've updated the code to handle this case.